# Probability of drawing balls from an urn with variable composition

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A coin is tossed $k$ times, with probability $p$ of heads. In an urn, as many white balls are introduced as the amount of heads obtained, and as many black balls are introduced as the amount of tails obtained. After this, $r$ $(r < k)$ balls are drawn, without replacing them.

Calculate the probability of $i$ white balls being drawn.

My try: I know that the composition of the urns is modeled by a binomial random variable. If $A$ is the event of $i$ white balls being drawn, and $B_j$ is the circumstance 'the urn has $j$ white balls and $k-j$ black balls', I can use the total probability theorem to express $P(A)$, but I don't know how one would reason to calculate an expression for $P(A|B_j)$. I understand that if the problem states 'without replacement', the balls are being drawn one by one, which only makes matters more difficult.

I'd like to know a reasoning to calculate the expression for $P(A|B_j)$, assuming the $r$ balls are being drawn one by one, and assuming the balls are drawn all at once.

Answer (score 0):

It is just binomial with $r$ trials and probability $p$ of being white.
Every time you toss a coin, immediately set aside a white or black ball.
When you choose $r$ from $k$ balls, you are choose $r$ from $k$ independent coin tosses, which is just $r$ independent coin tosses.

Comment: I want the probability of drawing $i$ white balls. $i$ is not necessarily equal to $r$. This probability depends on the composition of the urn.

Comment: @hallaplay835: The answer is correct. You don't need to worry about the composition of the urn. Each ball you draw, no matter which ones you draw, was chosen to be white with probability $p$. (Also, the answer doesn't assume that $i=r$, as you seem to have interpreted it.)